# live reload not working after upgrading yo grunt-cli bower

Tags: yeoman, gruntjs, bower

I Just built Nodejs and installed 0.10.6 then uninstalled yo+grunt-cli+bower+generator-webapp and reinstalled to latest using npm -g, 
yo webapp
But now live reload doesnt work, cant see any errors either in chrome devtools

yo -v: 1.0beta5
grunt-cli v0.1.8 and grunt v0.4.1
bower -v: 0.9.2
node -v: 0.10.6
npm -v: 1.2.18

grunt server shows the watch task: time + the name of file changed

tried : changing the port number in Gruntfile to.. LIVERELOAD_PORT = 34729;  nogo :(
my older webapp projects still work fine 
Lost..

Thanks
---------------------  UPDATE 
 1. moved lrSnippet to 1st position in Grunfile.js
 2. in index.js moved

```
    end.call(res, res.data, encoding);
```

outside the if Block

Now it works Partially :
**summary :** 
1. changes to index.html > reloads ok
2. changes to main.scss > reloads ok
3. changes to my.sass > Not OK

after 3rd step 
1. changes to index.html > Not OK
2. changes to main.scss > Not OK

4. changes to hello.coffe > Not OK
After step 4
1. changes to index.html > ok
2. changes to main.scss > ok

//------------------------------------- index.html 
Changes to index.html 
reload ok
grunt server window logs change and issues reload command

grunt server window grab =

```
    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...OK
    >> File "app/index.html" changed.

    Running "watch" task
    ... Reload app/index.html ...
    Completed in 0.002s at Sat May 18 2013 12:47:58 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
```

//------------------------------------- main.scss
Changes to main.scss
reload ok
grunt server window grab =

```
    >> File "app/styles/main.scss" changed.

    Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    overwrite .tmp/styles/main.css 
    unchanged app/styles/my.sass

    Running "watch" task
    Completed in 1.906s at Sat May 18 2013 12:48:24 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
    OK
    >> File ".tmp/styles/main.css" changed.

    Running "watch" task
    ... Reload .tmp/styles/main.css ...
    Completed in 0.002s at Sat May 18 2013 12:48:24 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
```

//------------------------------------- my.sass
changes to my.sass
reload not ok  (not reloading)
grunt server window grab =

```
    Running "watch" task
    Waiting...OK
    >> File "app/styles/my.sass" changed.

    Running "compass:server" (compass) task
    unchanged app/styles/main.scss
    unchanged .tmp/images/generated/design-s65ab268e46.png
    overwrite .tmp/styles/my.css 

    Running "watch" task
    Completed in 0.602s at Sat May 18 2013 13:00:19 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
```

//------------------------------------- 
After the my.sass is changed 
changes made to index.html or main.scss r not shown in grunt server window

the Watch command doesnt log anything.
changes r not reloaded
//-------------------------------------
Restarted Grunt Server
//------------------------------------- hello.coffee

grunt server window grab =

```
    OK
    >> File "app/scripts/hello.coffee" changed.

    Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task
    File .tmp/scripts/hello.js created.

    Running "watch" task
    Completed in 0.011s at Sat May 18 2013 13:34:56 GMT+0530 (IST) - Waiting...
```

//-------------------------------------

Comment: tried yo webapp again .. nogo .. works partially.. see above for details
├── connect-livereload@0.1.4
├─┬ grunt-contrib-connect@0.2.0
│ └─┬ connect@2.7.9
├─┬ grunt-contrib-compass@0.2.0
├─┬ grunt-contrib-watch@0.4.3

Answer (score 2):

There is a bug with the current livereload/yo setup. Here are the details alongside a fix for the problematic dependency (connect-livereload).

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/issues/63

Comment: tried ur suggestion, now it works partially.. changes to .coffee and .sass r not reloaded, furthermore after changes to .sass, changes to .html or .scss r not loaded

Comment: @ritin Interesting. I know there are sass and coffeescript workflow issues in generator-webapp. I'll verify this in about 8 to 9 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

Three things which you can make sure to diagnose the issue further.

1. Make sure you're on the latest version `npm update -g yo`
2. You shouldn't be using LiveReload plugin explicitly, it conflicts with Yeoman watch command while running
3. Your port (in gruntfile.js) might be using by some other process, try to exit from the terminal, change the port and it see it works or not.

The problem is yeoman doesn't change the port automatically in the current version, that's where it stopped working if you close it forcefully in the current terminal session.

The same issue has been discussed here - https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/issues/938

If you still see the issue then try to run the following command and past the output here.

```
yo --version && echo $PATH $NODE_PATH && node -e 'console.log(process.platform, process.versions)' && cat Gruntfile.js
```

Answer (score 0):

A commit was made to solve this problem.

https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/pull/67

We'll see an update soon I guess.

in the meantime what you can do is modify your Gruntfile.js. Look near the line 61 for the connect option for livereload and replace the configuration for this snippet.

```
livereload: {
  options: {
    middleware: function (connect) {
      return [
       lrSnippet,
       mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
       mountFolder(connect, yeomanConfig.app)
      ];
    }
  }
},
```

Also, is a good idea to update the module connect-livereload to 0.1.4.

Just run `npm install connect-livereload` on your project directory.

Answer (score 0):

I added live reload as an option under watch in the Gruntfile.js:

```
    watch: {
        options: {
            nospawn: true,
            livereload: true
        },
```

Setting the livereload:port instead of livereload:options:port worked for me:

```
livereload: {
  port: 35728
}
```